# Visiting menu alias for external URL type shows 404

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

Joomla Version: 3.7.4. I have created a menu item as below:

```
Menu Alias: testalias
Menu Item Type: External URL
Link: http://mywebsite.com/?userid=170
```

When I visit `mywebsite.com/testalias`, a 404 error is shown. How can I view `http://mywebsite.com/?userid=170` page content by visiting `mywebsite.com/testalias`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
- menu item type: system links > menu item alias
- menu item: select the menu item that links to userid=170

If you don't have a menu item that links to userid=170 (in the second step above), remember you could create a hidden menu and add mysite.com/testalias to the hidden menu.

===
Edit
I've tested that the following method will work as well in the case where you can't create a menu item alias.

Using sh404SEF, create a new alias.
alias: testalias
target url: http://mywebsite.com/?userid=170

After you save you will be able to use http://mywebsite.com/testalias

Good luck

Comment: I tried doing that but External URL menu items are not being shown in 'Select' while creating menu item alias.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are wanting to use 'external url'? If I'm understanding your question correctly, a menu item type of system link will work. @SR

Comment: Component does not have a menu option to select userid. But one of it's menu item allows to pass userid as parameter. I wish to call http://mywebsite.com/?userid=170 using http://mywebsite.com/testalias. @David